# Side Effects when allowing longer Meta Descriptions

Tags: database, meta-description

Since the meta_description attribute has a varchar backend type, the input is limited to 255. However nowadays Google supports longer meta description.

If the backend type of meta_description is changed from varchar to text, the descriptions will no longer be stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, but `catalog_product_entity_text` instead. Will this have any negative side effects? Should the old meta descriptions be imported into `catalog_product_entity_text` and removed from `catalog_product_entity_varchar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the old meta descriptions be imported into `catalog_product_entity_text` and removed from `catalog_product_entity_varchar`?

Yes, I think so (not testet, but I doubt that magento moves them on his own) ... Update script could look like this: 
[Magento attribute change backend_type from varchar to text](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103444/magento-attribute-change-backend-type-from-varchar-to-text) (or you use `insertFromSelect()` method).

> However nowadays Google supports longer meta description.

In the past google showed up to 170 chars, now it's up 300 **for desktop** and 200 **for mobiles**, so I would not change it to more then 200, but this is really opinion-based.

If you change the length, do not forget to also change frontend class for products and categories otherwise your are not able to save longer descriptions from backend.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET frontend_class = 'validate-length maximum-length-XXX' WHERE attribute_code = 'meta_description';
UPDATE eav_attribute SET note = 'Maximum XXX chars' WHERE attribute_code = 'meta_description';
```