# Increase maximum chars for meta description

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, meta-description

The [Google's limit for the meta description](https://moz.com/learn/seo/meta-description), from some months to today, is around 300 characters.

So, I'd like to increase the limit of 255 chars in Magento 1.9

How can I do it in a clean way? :)

p.s.
My question [is different from this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103444/magento-attribute-change-backend-type-from-varchar-to-text) 'cause I want to know if there is a way to maintain the meta description field on the DB as a numeric field, but only with an increased limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento attribute change backend\_type from varchar to text](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103444/magento-attribute-change-backend-type-from-varchar-to-text)

Comment: If you make this change, you also have to change field validation .... see: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212555/side-effects-when-allowing-longer-meta-descriptions

Comment: My question is not a duplicate. I ask if it's possible to increase the numeric limit, not to change a numeric field into a string one.

Comment: Meta description is stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`. This table is limited to 255 chars. If you want a longer description, you have change it to `catalog_product_entity_text` ... IMHO it is a duplicate :P

Answer (score 1):

Update meta description maximum length via upgrade script

Use below code for update maximum length

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$entityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'meta_description', 'frontend_class', 'validate-length maximum-length-300');
```

**OR**

```
$installer  = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$entityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'meta_description', 'frontend_class', 'validate-length maximum-length-300');

$installer->endSetup();
```

By Default magento1 set `maximum length: 255`

Please see here defualt 
 code `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\sql\catalog_setup\mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.39-1.4.0.0.40.php`

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response. So, to use this code I've to create the same .php file under app/code/local... Is correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Firstly, run the following code to change the attributes from `varchar` to `text` and move them into the right tables. Make sure you **back up your website and database first!**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM rds_eav_attribute WHERE entity_type_id = 4 AND attribute_code = "meta_description");
UPDATE rds_eav_attribute SET frontend_class = 'validate-length maximum-length-XXX' WHERE attribute_code = 'meta_description';
UPDATE rds_eav_attribute SET backend_type = 'text' WHERE attribute_id = @attribute_id;
UPDATE rds_eav_attribute SET note = 'Maximum XXX chars' WHERE attribute_code = 'meta_description';
INSERT INTO rds_catalog_product_entity_text SELECT * FROM rds_catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = @attribute_id;
DELETE FROM rds_catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = @attribute_id;
COMMIT;
```

Because it was the meta description I'm changing, I also had to change `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Attributes.php` lines 117-119 from:

```
if ($form->getElement('meta_description')) {
    $form->getElement('meta_description')->setOnkeyup('checkMaxLength(this, 255);');
}
```

to:

```
if ($form->getElement('meta_description')) {
    $form->getElement('meta_description');
}
```

Instead of hacking the core file though, I'd copy the file to `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Attributes.php` (although even this isn't recommended, but it's a workaround for the time being. Hopefully we'll see this changed in the Magento core at a later date.

Comment: Hi Liam and thanks for your response :)
So there is no way to do this operation without to change the DB I see...

Comment: The database definitely needs changing unfortunately because the `varchar` type is set in the database that needs changing to text, and the current records need moving to the text table to prevent any database discrepancies. It's a pain, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

@Abdul is right.

You can also update the note bellow the field.

```
<?php

/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$entityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'meta_description', 'frontend_class', 'validate-length maximum-length-300');
$installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'meta_description', 'note', 'Maximum 300 chars');
```

And you also need an observer to change the front side validation.

```
/**
 * @var $observer Varien_Event_Observer
 */
public function updateMetaDescription(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /**
     * @var $form Varien_Data_Form
     */
    $form = $observer->getForm();
    $metaDescription = $form->getElement('meta_description');
    if($metaDescription){
        $metaDescription->setOnkeyup('checkMaxLength(this, 300);');
    }
}
```